# I have setup AWS cognito with my own user pool, when i create a user having phone number of united state I don't receive verification SMS on phone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have set-up AWS Cognito with my own custom User Pool. When I enter the phone number of an Indian citizen, I receive the SMS verification message. However, if I enter phone number of a US Citizen, I don't get the message. Please help me to debug it. Let me know if further information is required.

Comment: Please provide with AWS SNS logs.